# View map in mode satellite and terrain

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I tried to create a menu on the screen, where the menu will display the map in satellite mode and terrain.

My code:

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
  switch (item.getItemId()) {
  case MENU_MyLocation:
   //startActivity(new Intent(this, MyLocation.class));
   return(true);
  case MENU_LocationCar:
   startActivity(new Intent(this, Gps.class));
   return(true);
  case MENU_Satellite:
      map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
       return(true);
  case MENU_Terrain:
      map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN);
   return(true);
  }

  return(super.onOptionsItemSelected(item));
}
```

Comment: please explain the functionality you want to achieve or the issue you are facing

Comment: I want an application that I created to show Maps in satellite and terrain mode. Can you help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to refresh the `MapView` after you make the changes to its settings by calling `invalidate()`.
So your code will look something like

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
  switch (item.getItemId()) {
  case MENU_MyLocation:
   //startActivity(new Intent(this, MyLocation.class));
   return(true);
  case MENU_LocationCar:
   startActivity(new Intent(this, Gps.class));
   return(true);
  case MENU_Satellite:
      map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
      map.invalidate();
       return(true);
  case MENU_Terrain:
      map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN);
      map.invalidate();
   return(true);
  }

  return(super.onOptionsItemSelected(item));
}
```

Comment: how to refresh MapView? sorry I am just learning about the android.

Comment: I get "method invalidate is undefined for the type GoogleMap", so this did not work for me.